# Change multiple class on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a little problem. I have `<li>` elements and I want to change their
background color on each click. In my code, I am trying to count the clicks.
If the click = 1, then the background color would be red. If the click = 2, then the background color would be blue. If the click = 3, the background color would revert to the original and the count will be back to 0;

[Here is my
jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8s3D/11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
$(function() {    
    $("#sortable li").each(function() {
        var count = 0;
        $(this).click(function(){
        count++;
        if (count === 1) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
        }
        else if(count === 2){
            $(this).removeClass('on');
            $(this).addClass('absent');
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('absent');
            count = 0;
        }
        });
    });
});​
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/j8s3D/12/

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. Will you please give me an explanation as to how you did it? I seem to have difficulty in understanding jquery codes since I'm really new at it.

Comment: he loops the collection of li's, creating a local variable named count, adds a click event that affect the local variable

Comment: first, because each button has its independent count, so I think you should use jquery.each first. see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ then you have already use one `count++;`, so there is no need to use too much `++`.

Answer (score 1):

You increment `count` too much!
Note that you can cache the `$(this)` object rather than construct new jQuery object on every line!

**Fixed code:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable li").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var count = $this.data('count') || 1;

        if (count === 1) {
            $this.addClass('on');
        }
        else if (count === 2) {
            $this.removeClass('on').addClass('absent');
        }
        else {
            $this.removeClass('absent');
            count = 1;            
        }
        $this.data('count', count+1);
    });
});​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8s3D/23/)

Comment: Oh! so that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: @user1056998. notice how I chained the jQuery code: `$this.removeClass('on').addClass('absent');`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the .data() to keep track on the specific lis 'state' (or you just if it has a specific cssClass and not use a counter, but if you want to keep the counter: http://jsfiddle.net/j8s3D/13/

Answer (score 1):

```
var arry = ['red', 'blue','orange'], i=0, len= arry.length;
$('#element').on('click',function(){  
  $(this).css('background',arry[i++]);
    if(i===len){i=0;}
})​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NarBh/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.data()` to associate the number with the element. You should also cache `$(this)` and maybe use a switch instead of an if/else structure. Finally, you can chain the `removeClass`and `adddClass` methods. http://jsfiddle.net/pXFs6/

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable li").click(function() {
        $ele = $(this);
        count = $ele.data().count || 1;

        switch(count) {
            case 1:
                $ele.addClass('on');
                break;
            case 2:
                $ele.removeClass('on')
                    .addClass('absent');
                break;
            default:
                $ele.removeClass('absent');
                count = 0;
                break;
        }
        $ele.data('count', count+1);

    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer you another variant (a little bit optimized):

```
$(function() {    
    $("#sortable li").each(function() {
        var count = 0;
        $(this).click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            count++;
        if (count === 1) {
            $this.addClass('on');
        }
        else if(count === 2){
            $this.addClass('absent');
        }
        else{
            $this.removeAttr('class');
            count = 0;
        }
        });
    }); });​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8s3D/24/)